# Totally Dynamic Form Creation: MVC or WebForms?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, dynamic, webforms

I'll start a new project, that will include forms whose inputs and their types (textbox, checkbox etc), Validation rules are defined in DB.

I have to choose one of the frameworks for **Form Creation**, **Form Validation**, **Edit/Insert Forms** but I'm stuck. I doubt MVC will make handling **Parent-Child relationship** for Controls difficult. And although WebForms will help me behave all dynamic inputs as objects, I'm worried i will have to deal with **Reflection** for simple things.

Any clues for this hesitant person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct with the Parent-Child Relationship problem for MVC. From what I can tell, it would be pain in the butt. I do not think you will need reflection for WebForms, as long as you can somehow get the controls into an array.

My vote: WebForms.

Comment: Thank youu!! I also think so, but flexibility of MVC confuses my mind. I'll wait for one day to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

I have used regular asp.net (web forms) for completely dynamic interfaces, no need for reflection for any of it. That said, I really don't think you will find any of them blocking your way to achieve it.
You also might want to look at http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/

Ps. for completely dynamic, I mean interfaces through an admin UI say which table(s), which columns, add validation metadata, labels :)

Comment: I agree but i think your "completely dynamic" term is related to fields-as-TableColumns, not fields defined in Table Rows. Is Dynamic Data so flexible?

Comment: That was long time ago, but we did support configuration for child relations, I created an inherited version of the datagrid (back then, there were no gridview, listview, or any of those :(), but I don't recall if that was because of the dynamic req. or something else.

Comment: Regarding Dynamic Data I just know it is for a related scenario, but I haven't really used it, so I am not sure whether it supports all of these